CMake not finding the right boost
I am having following error with CMake. I wasn't sure what I did changed how it finds boost. I am supposed to use another boost of 1.64, but it seems it kept looking for 1.74. Not sure why. Here is the error message.
Sonar coverage enabled: 
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.74.0/BoostConfig.cmake:141 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "boost_system"
  (requested version 1.74.0) with any of the following names:

    boost_systemConfig.cmake
    boost_system-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "boost_system" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "boost_system_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "boost_system" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.74.0/BoostConfig.cmake:258 (boost_find_component)
  /home/xcui/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/clion/bin/cmake/linux/x64/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:594 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:492 (find_package)

How do I make the CMake to find the right boost? Any pointer is highly appreciated.

You could specify path of the desired Boost installation with -DBOOST_ROOT=<path/to/boost> parameter to cmake, as suggested in that answer.
